# Books in foundations of mathematical logic

Tags: reference-request, logic

I'm a civil engineer that spends all of its free time (with the permission of my wife and my two children) studying set theory and mathematical logic. For instance, I've read and enjoyed "Axiomatic set Theory" by Suppes, Enderton's "Elements of set theory","Mathematical logic" by Shoenfield or "A course in mathematical logic" by Bell and Machover. Now, my goals are the history and the development of these two mathematical branches. 
In this sense I'm reading  "Foundations of Set Theory" by Fraenkel, Bar-hilleil and levy or "Labyrinth of thought" by José Ferreirós and I would like to have in the same line as the above good books in the foundations of mathematical logic.

Thank you in advance

Comment: 2 recommendations geared to category theory: Lawvere & Rosebrugh: "Set Theory for Mathematics" 2003. Paul Taylor "Practical Foundations of Mathematics" 1999.

Answer (score 4):

The reading list/study guide linked at http://www.logicmatters.net/students/tyl/ is only half done yet [reminder to self to get on with it!] but might contain  one or two helpful suggestions.

Comment: Perfect this is a good starting point. Yhanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You might like the book "Foundations of Mathematics" by William S. Hatcher.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in van Heijenoort's From Frege To Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic, 1879-1931.

On a different line, I recommend Dauben's biography of Cantor, and his more recent Battle for Cantorian Set Theory.

Comment: I already looked up "From Frege to Godel" but although is a great collection of articles written by those who actually built up the foundations of mathematics, what I'm interested in is a book that covers from 1870 and 1940 just in the line of From Frege to Godel but maybe written by a unique author in the same way as Jose Ferreiros does in the "Labyrinth of thought". However articles of different authors as provided in the former book are good enough in the book Philosophy of Mathematics:selected readings by Paul Benacerraf and hilary Putman.

Answer (score 1):

[*Introduction to Mathematical Thinking*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615653634) is a very good book in my opinion. It is even more effective when you read it along with the courseware of [the course by the same name](https://www.coursera.org/course/maththink).

Comment: This is course for people who did not have any decent contact with mathematics like students of social sciences.

Comment: I took it. It is a great course

Answer (score 0):

*Foundations of Mathematical Logic* by Haskell B. Curry is a good book on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interest in knowing it's application in Computer Science then you can go for Discrete Mathematical Structures With Applications to Computer Science -  Jean Paul Tremblay, Rampurkar Manohar .